# Couldn't print to this printer: Failed to copy file to printer. Error shown while using mike42

Tags: php, printing, escpos

Im working on PHP based web application for booking. The guest room owner wants to use Black Copper BC-90AC thermal printer, which is USB printer for generating receipt. So I want to use mike42/escpos-php for the purpose. I have included the library into my project using composer install, however when I run a test page, I get following error.

> Warning: copy(\DESKTOP-5O5GGB3\Receipt Printer): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\escpos-php\src\Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector.php on line 378
> Couldn't print to this printer: Failed to copy file to printer

Whether I connect thermal printer to my laptop or not, I get this error. Please suggest where Im doing wrong.

Here is the php example code which is giving me above error:

```
<?php
 require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
 use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
 use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;

 try {
    $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("myprinter");

    /* Print a "Hello world" receipt" */
    $printer = new Printer($connector);
    $printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
    $printer -> cut();

    /* Close printer */
    $printer -> close();
 } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n";
 }
```

Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: I suppose the printer must be connected to the server where PHP is running... client-side conntected printers are controlled by the clients OS - the browser should be able to use it without any programming

Comment: This is not an ESC/POS question.  Consider removing the escpos tag.

Comment: @MarcBalmer The printer is ESC/POS and I'm using mike42 ESCPOS-PHP library, that's why I added escpos tag.

Comment: It's not mike42 ESCPOS-PHP library, but could this article be helpful? [Print HTML from PHP directly to the client printer without print dialog or silent mode](https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/Print-HTML-from-PHP-to-client-printer-without-print-dialog-silently/)

Answer (score 4):

Share the printer from printer settings and it should work.

Comment: Yes I was getting same problem. Sharing my EPSON T83III printer solved the problem.